# Missing website template when trying to edit a post with pending suggested edit

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

today I tried to edit a question ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37236930/edit)), but when I clicked "edit" all I saw was this:

[image: missing template when trying to edit a question with pending suggested edit]

As you can see from the screenshot, there is no SO template at all.
Is this a bug?

If I try to edit it now, I get redirected to the edit form as expected.

Comment: Did you read that text below? There's already another edit pending in the edit review queue. You have to wait until it's accepted or rejected before you can suggest another edit.

Comment: IIRC it should be a red warning popup and not another page.  What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know what it means, I was just wondering why there was only this sentence with no template at all..

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am using Google Chrome v 50.0.2661.102 on Windows 8.1

Comment: @Fabio I probably misunderstood your question.